# 配列に条件を満たすものがあるか判定する一番かっこいい書き方

Tags: python

配列の中に条件を満たすものが1個でもあるかどうかを、見つかった時点でループを打ち切るように判定したいです。

以下の様に書くしかないですか？Lambda を使って1行で書く方法はないでしょうか。

環境:
Ubuntu
Python 3.7.5

```
flag = false
for x in range(10):
  if x == 5:
    flag = true
    break
```

Comment: 動いたんですが思ってた関数ではなかったです。　中身が boolean の配列に使うもので lambda をわたせる関数じゃなかったです。

Comment: うまくいきました！　第３引数が関数だったのですね

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`any`を使ったらこんな感じですね．

```py
>>> any(i == 5 for i in range(10))
True
>>> any(i == 11 for i in range(10))
False
```

Comment: 素敵です　使わせてもらいます　 range(0x7fffffff) にしてもすぐ終わるのでみつかった時点でるーぷでてくれるんですね